# Transform file to data: format

Tags: css, string, file, base64

I'm wondering how I can transform this :

```
  url(../font/font2.woff)format('woff');
```

to

```
url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAF7EABMAAAAArmwAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\
        AAAAAAAABGRlRNAAABqAAAABwAAAAca+V....)format('woff');
```

I want to to transform a **data file** to a **String** on **base64**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a base64 file encoder to convert the file into base64 format. Here's an online site that converts files for you: http://jpillora.com/base64-encoder/.

Then replace the string within the parentheses of `url()`

Comment: that what I was looking for